# PowerShell 'Cannot find overload' when calling SOAP API method

Tags: powershell, soap

I am trying to call a SOAP API method using PowerShell and have trouble passing parameters to it.

I am able to authenticate and have all required permissions. The method is available.
According to the Docs and WDSL it has 4 required parameters `datetime`,`datetime`,`bool`,`int`. I am passing them but the result is always the same error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "GetFirstPageAlarms" and the argument count: "4".
  At line:1 char:1
+ $alarmz = $Client.GetFirstPageAlarms([datetime]$endDate,[datetime]$en ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Here are my attempts:

```
# Connect to the API
$Client = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url -Credential get-credential

# Connects successfully

# Define parameters
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-2)
$endDate = get-date
$allUsers = $true
$maximumResultsPerPage = 10

# Call the method
$results = $Client.GetFirstPageAlarms([datetime]$endDate,[datetime]$endDate,[boolean]$True,[int]"5")
# Fails here.

# Alternative, also fails with same error
$Client.GetFirstPageAlarms("2020-11-01","2020-12-01","True","5")

# And another alternative failing
$Client.GetFirstPageAlarms([datetime]"2020-11-01",[datetime]"2020-12-01",[boolean]$True,[int]"5")
```

From Googling it seems the `Overload` error is associated with wrong types of required parameters. I tried to specify the types but it is still failing.

I have tried more things and looked everywhere for information, running out of options and ideas. I hope somebody can help. Thanks!

The WSDL definition for the method:

```
<xs:element name="GetFirstPageAlarms">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="startDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="allUsers" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maximumResultsPerPage" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Link to the API Docs:
https://docs.logrhythm.com/docs/lrapi/soap-api-logrhythm-7-x-x/soap-api-reference-guide-logrhythm-7-x-x/soap-api-reference-alarmservice/soap-api-alarmservice-methods#SOAPAPIAlarmService,Methods-getfirstpagealarms

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is solved:

```
$client | get-member GetFirstPageAlarms
```

returns

```
TypeName   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1ices_AlarmServiceBasicAuth_svc.AlarmService

Name       : GetFirstPageAlarms

MemberType : Method

Definition : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1ices_AlarmServiceBasicAuth_svc.AlarmSummaryDataResults GetFirstPageAlarms(datetime startDate, bool startDateSpecified, datetime

             endDate, bool endDateSpecified, bool allUsers, bool allUsersSpecified, int maximumResultsPerPage, bool maximumResultsPerPageSpecified)
```

Theres some hidden properties that needed to be added. For some reason the docs don't mention them.

```
$Client.GetFirstPageAlarms([datetime]"2020-11-01",[bool]$true,[datetime]"2020-12-01",[bool]$true,[bool]$true,[bool]$true,[int]"5",[bool]$true)
```

Have a new error:

```
Exception calling "GetFirstPageAlarms" with "8" argument(s): "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Client.GetFirstPageAlarms([datetime]"2020-11-01",[bool]$true,[dateti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapHeaderException
```

But this is probably a separate issue not related to the question in the OP.